# Crossed guides in Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

On the "**what's new in Illustrator**" there are some new features, but on my MacBook Pro the features 1 and 2 do not work. Could some one check them for me - do you have them working?
Is there any way to enable these features?

> In Illustrator CC, there are enhancements to guides:
>
> 1. **Double-clicking on a ruler** (Ctrl/Cmd + R) creates a guide at
>    that specific location on the ruler. When you hold Shift and then
>    double-click a specific location on a ruler, the guide created at the
>    point automatically snaps to the closest division (mark) on the ruler.
> 2. Create horizontal and vertical Guides **in one action**. Here’s how:
>    At the top-left corner of the Illustrator window, left-click the
>    intersection of the Rulers, press Ctrl (or Cmd on a Mac), and drag the
>    mouse pointer to any location in the Illustrator window. The mouse
>    pointer becomes cross hairs to indicate where a horizontal and
>    vertical guide can be created. Release the mouse pointer to create the
>    Guides.

Comment: u're right - my is cs16 and CC is 17 subscribtion-only version. sad to realise that after buying %(

Comment: Made my comment an answer.

Comment: I am waiting for some one else who can check the features on CS16...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **Illustrator CS6**, then the features you mentioned won't work. The quote says **Illustrator CC** (Creative Cloud), but your title says CS6.

> In **Illustrator CC**, there are enhancements to guides: